# Is java dynamic synchronization a good idea or allowed?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, locking

Basically, what is needed is to synchronize requests to each of the records.
Some of the codes I can think of is like this:

```
//member variable
ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Object> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Object>();

//one method
private void maintainLockObjects(long id){
    lockMap.putIfAbsent(id, new Object());
}

//the request method
bar(long id){
    maintainLockObjects(id);

    synchronized(lockMap.get(id)){
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use third-party libraries?  If so, consider Guava's [Striped](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html), which provides a somewhat more flexible alternative that lets you balance memory and concurrency.

Comment: To test if it's allowed, you could simply compile the code and test it.

Comment: Striped is promising, however, the system I modified is on Java 5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getClassLoadingLock-java.lang.String-):

> Returns the lock object for class loading operations. For backward compatibility, the default implementation of this method behaves as follows. If this ClassLoader object is registered as parallel capable, the method returns a dedicated object associated with the specified class name. Otherwise, the method returns this ClassLoader object.

Its implementation code may look familiar to you:

```
protected Object getClassLoadingLock(String className) {
    Object lock = this;
    if (parallelLockMap != null) {
        Object newLock = new Object();
        lock = parallelLockMap.putIfAbsent(className, newLock);
        if (lock == null) {
            lock = newLock;
        }
    }
    return lock;
}
```

The first `null` check is only for the mentioned backwards compatibility. So besides that, the only difference between this heavily used code and your approach is that this code avoids to call `get` afterwards as `putIfAbsent` already returns the old object if there is one.

So the simply answer, it works and this pattern also proving within a really crucial part of Oracle’s JRE implementation.